# change event not firing in IE for the first time

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, file-upload

```
$(this).find('.custom-file-input').trigger('click');
$(this).find(".custom-file-input").off().on('change', function (){
....
}
```

Above is my code snippet, I am trying to trigger the click of a file upload input, which opens the file open dialog and then on change, I am trying to execute some code. In IE, for the first time, It doesn't work.

While in chrome and firefox, its working with success every time.

Comment: is it showing any error in console?

Comment: Have you tried reversing the order - bind the change handler first, before you trigger the click event? (And what’s .off() good for in there?)

Comment: @CBroe, It worked, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you try changing the order?

```
$(this).find(".custom-file-input").on('change', function (){
....
}
$(this).find('.custom-file-input').trigger('click');
```